# Spring Boot app on Google App Engine: unable to find main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Spring Boot app that runs on GCP (for 1 year now) and I would like to update it but when I run `mvn appengine:run` localy I have this error:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFOS: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the main class to restart
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.doStart(Restarter.java:277)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.start(Restarter.java:265)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.lambda$immediateRestart$0(Restarter.java:173)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$LeakSafeThread.run(Restarter.java:637)
[INFO] GCLOUD: d?c. 02, 2018 4:30:20 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService cleanupActiveServices
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFOS: scheduler shutting down.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  53.255 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-02T17:30:21+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run (default-cli) on project sample-app: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run (default-cli) on project tacos-time29: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run failed: Non zero exit: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
```

There is a problem with the main class. In my pom.xm I defined this:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin>
    <!--Definition of the main class-->
    <start-class>com.example.sample.Application</start-class>
</properties>
```

I also defined the main class in the spring-boot-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the content of `/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` file is basic:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: For me too and I don't understand the reason of this exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/294
Just remove the `devtools` dependency. It's a really strange behavior